# meaning of the phrase "issue of quantum of"

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context

I often find the phrase "issue of quantum of" in the rulings made by the U.S courts like these:

> The substance of the argument is that the court deciding **the issue of
>   quantum of damages** would be better suited to decide the proper scale
>   of costs.
>
> He asked the court to determine the issue of fault ahead of **the issue
>   of quantum of** damages.
>
> However, **on the issue of quantum of** sentence, the High Court found
>   favour with the submission made by the counsel for the appellant.

Could you kindly tell me what the phrase "the issue of quantum (of)" means?
I looked up the phrase in the dictionary but I couldn't find any relevant information.

Comment: Read *issue of* as "question of" and independent of "quantum of". "The substance of the argument is that the court deciding the **question of** (the) quantum of damages would be better suited to decide the proper scale of costs." HTH.

Comment: Avoid saying *“the **below** X”* because this can sound stilted and even
borderline unnatural to native speakers. Instead say *“the **following** 
X”* in especially formal written contexts, or merely *“**this** X”* in the
singular or *“**these** Xes”* in the plural in many common and less
exacting circumstances. Sometimes English-language learners don’t realize
that they should use the demonstrative determiners *this, that, these,
those* which native speakers customarily use for these cases.

Comment: @tchrist thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe in this case your confusion is probably due to the word *quantum*. One of the OED's definitions for [quantum](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/155941?redirectedFrom=quantum#eid) is as follows:

> Total amount or quantity; … in later use chiefly *law* (with reference to amounts of money)

So here, *quantum* is being used in legal settings to discuss the **amount** of money (damages) or the **length** of the sentence. *Issue* simply refers to an important topic here. The first example you provided is simply positing that the proper scale of costs should be determined on the basis of whatever damages the court decides upon.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, Taylor. However, I'm afraid your explanation may not fit into the sentence ""Accordingly, there is no need for me to deal with Springwell's appeal on the issue of quantum of the Post-Default Appeal.". Could you kindly elaborate more on this one?

Comment: I had to go look for this specific case because context is clearly needed to get an appreciation for the full picture. In the introduction, "Post-Default claims" are mentioned. I'm guessing that a previous ruling was made, which struck down these Post-Default claims. No damages were thus awarded. The Post-Default *appeal* seems to be an appeal of the dismissal of these claims, which are monetary in nature. The judge found that the appeal was unfounded and as such is not going to entertain any judgment on the *quantum* of the appeal—in other words, the amount of damages.

Comment: Taylor, I really appreciate your great explanation.

Comment: Happy to help! Thank you for accepting my answer.